# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'setup' was never awaited setup(self) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, pycord

can someone help me? i'm tryng to add edited embed on my discord bot
using pycord but something is missing.. i don't know..

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

```
class Myview(discord.ui.View):

def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:

    self.bot = bot
    super().__init__()
    

@discord.ui.select(
    placeholder = 'Escolha uma Copy!',
    options = [
        discord.SelectOption(label = 'Embed editada', value = '1', description = 'isto é uma embed editada', emoji = ''),
        discord.SelectOption(label = 'Embed editada2', value = '2', description = 'isto é uma embed editada 2', emoji = ''),
        discord.SelectOption(label = 'Embed editada3', value = '3', description = 'isto é uma embed editada 3', emoji = '')
        ]
)
async def select_callback(self, select, interaction):
    select.disable = True
    if select.values[0] == '1':
        em = discord.Embed()
        em.set_author(name = 'isto é uma embed editada')
        em.add_field(name = 'charlie', value = 'text1', inline = False)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=em)
    
    if select.values[0] == '2':
        em2 = discord.Embed()
        em.set_author(name = 'isto é uma embed editada2')
        em.add_field(name = 'charlie2', value = 'texto 2', inline = False)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=em2)
    
    if select.values[0] == '3':
        em3 = discord.Embed()
        em.set_author(name = 'isto é uma embed editada3')
        em.add_field(name = 'charlie3', value = 'text 3', inline = False)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed = em3)
        
@commands.command(name = "teste menu seleção")
async def copys(self, ctx):
    view = Myview()
    await ctx.send("copys", view = view)

async def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
await bot.add_view(Myview(bot))
```

i just don't know what to do to fix this..
every time i run get this message...

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'setup' was never awaited
setup(self)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Answer (score 0):

At the of your code! You've writed:

```
async def setup(bot: commands.Bot)
```

It should be:

```
def setup(bot: commands.Bot)
```

Also [`discord.Client.add_view`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=add_view#discord.Client.add_view) dont need to be awaited.

Comment: i changed but now i get ' Extension 'selecao.menudecomandos' raised an error: RuntimeError: no running event loop'

Comment: Are you using cogs?